# Using the difference or Soundex function in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to join names that are similar or exactly the same. 
Currently I have the following query:

```
    select 
    a.*,
    b.* 
    from #base a 
    inner join 
    #customerinfo b 
    on a.person1 = b.party name
```

this will join on most party names but not all. I also tried the 'like' function, but that gave me the same results. How would I do the Soundex or Difference function?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a percentage to which the names should match? Also, which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward, exactly as it sounds:

```
select 
a.*,
b.* 
from #base a 
inner join #customerinfo b on soundex(a.person1) = soundex(b.[party name]);
```

or using DIFFERENCE:

```
select 
a.*,
b.* 
from #base a 
inner join #customerinfo b on DIFFERENCE(a.person1, b.[party name]) = 4;
```